# How can I set My Json Value in Adapter

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

*I Am Having two JsonArray in Which there is JsonObject I have Got the String of each value but the problem is that when i am passing i into adapter I am getting indexOutofbound exeption because my value are getting Store in my object class so can any one help me how can i send my data to Object so that i can inflate to recyclerView.*

```
private void callola() {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(CabBookingActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading ...");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();

    final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(CabBookingActivity.this);
    String url = "https://www.reboundindia.com/app/application/ola/ride_estimate.php";
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Log.e("sushil Call ola response", response);

                    try {
                        JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                        String result = mainObj.getString("result");
                        int i, j;
                        ArrayList categoriess, Ride;

                        if (result.equals("606")) {
                            JSONObject message = mainObj.getJSONObject("message");
                            categories = message.getJSONArray("categories");
                            ride_estimate = message.getJSONArray("ride_estimate");

                            // JSONArray ride_estimate = message.getJSONArray("ride_estimate");
                            for (i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++) {

                                Log.e("sushil", String.valueOf(i));
                                jsonObject = categories.getJSONObject(i);
                                id = jsonObject.getString("id");
                                display_name = jsonObject.getString("display_name");
                                image = jsonObject.getString("image");
                                eta = jsonObject.getString("eta");
                                Log.e("OutPut", id + " " + eta + " " + image + " " + amount_min + " " + amount_max);

                            }
                            for (j = 0; j < ride_estimate.length(); j++) {
                                Log.e("sushil", String.valueOf(j));
                                rideestimate = ride_estimate.getJSONObject(j);
                                distance = rideestimate.getString("distance");
                                amount_min = rideestimate.getString("amount_min");
                                amount_max = rideestimate.getString("amount_max");
                                category = rideestimate.getString("category");

                            }



                        }

                        OlaUberModel olaUberModel = new OlaUberModel(category, display_name, amount_min, eta, image, amount_max);
                        arrayList.add(olaUberModel);
                        Log.e("sushil ride_estimate", distance + " " + amount_min + " " + amount_max);
                        AdapterOlaUber adapterOlaUber = new AdapterOlaUber(context, arrayList, CabBookingActivity.this);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterOlaUber);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Log.e("error", error.toString());

        }


    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

            params.put("pickup_lat", "" + pickLat);
            params.put("pickup_lng", "" + pickLong);
            params.put("drop_lat", String.valueOf(dropLat));
            params.put("drop_lng", String.valueOf(dropLong));
            params.put("category", "all");
            params.put("token", token);
            Log.e("sushil param", String.valueOf(params));

            return params;
        }
    };
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            90000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Here is my JSONRESPONSE

```
{  
   "result":"606",
   "message":{  
      "categories":[  
         {  
            "id":"micro",
            "display_name":"Micro",
            "currency":"INR",
            "distance_unit":"kilometre",
            "time_unit":"minute",
            "eta":5,
            "distance":"0.7",
            "ride_later_enabled":"true",
            "image":"http:\/\/d1foexe15giopy.cloudfront.net\/micro.png",
            "cancellation_policy":{  
               "cancellation_charge":50,
               "currency":"INR",
               "cancellation_charge_applies_after_time":5,
               "time_unit":"minute"
            },
            "fare_breakup":[  
               {  
                  "type":"flat_rate",
                  "minimum_distance":0,
                  "minimum_time":0,
                  "base_fare":50,
                  "minimum_fare":60,
                  "cost_per_distance":6,
                  "waiting_cost_per_minute":0,
                  "ride_cost_per_minute":1.5,
                  "surcharge":[  

                  ],
                  "rates_lower_than_usual":false,
                  "rates_higher_than_usual":false
               }
            ]
         },
         {  },
         {  },
         {  },
         {  },
         {  },
         {  },
         {  },
         {  }
      ],
      "ride_estimate":[  
         {  
            "category":"prime_play",
            "distance":3.99,
            "travel_time_in_minutes":30,
            "amount_min":155,
            "amount_max":163,
            "discounts":{  
               "discount_type":null,
               "discount_code":null,
               "discount_mode":null,
               "discount":0,
               "cashback":0
            }
         },
         {  },
         {  },
         {  },
         {  },
         {  },
         {  },
         {  }
      ]
   }
}
```

My Problem is that how can send the data in model.
My Model Should contain data Like id,displayName,amountMin,eta,image,amountMax

Comment: you should use gson library for the above purpose.That library will directly fill the model  class with data. For more detail please look  at this [Gson Intro](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-getting-started-with-java-json-serialization-deserialization)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to make two different models for category and ride_estimate.Because they both are in different loops. Also try this

```
for (j = 0; j < ride_estimate.length(); j++) {
                            Log.e("sushil", String.valueOf(j));
                            rideestimate = ride_estimate.getJSONObject(j);
                            distance = rideestimate.getString("distance");
                            amount_min = rideestimate.getString("amount_min");
                            amount_max = rideestimate.getString("amount_max");
                            category = rideestimate.getString("category");
```

OlaUberModel olaUberModel = new OlaUberModel(category, display_name, amount_min, eta, image, amount_max);
                        arrayList.add(olaUberModel);
                            }

May be this would helpful for you..
Thanks!

Comment: but i want image from and eta from categories loop

Answer (score 0):

**replace**

```
eta = jsonObject.getString("eta");
```

**by**

```
int eta = jsonObject.getInt("eta");
```

Answer (score 0):

On the basis of id of any cab type "prime" you can fetch image. what say

Answer (score 0):

create some class as per your data

```
-----------------------------------com.example.CancellationPolicy.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class CancellationPolicy {

@SerializedName("cancellation_charge")
@Expose
private Integer cancellationCharge;
@SerializedName("currency")
@Expose
private String currency;
@SerializedName("cancellation_charge_applies_after_time")
@Expose
private Integer cancellationChargeAppliesAfterTime;
@SerializedName("time_unit")
@Expose
private String timeUnit;

public Integer getCancellationCharge() {
return cancellationCharge;
}

public void setCancellationCharge(Integer cancellationCharge) {
this.cancellationCharge = cancellationCharge;
}

public String getCurrency() {
return currency;
}

public void setCurrency(String currency) {
this.currency = currency;
}

public Integer getCancellationChargeAppliesAfterTime() {
return cancellationChargeAppliesAfterTime;
}

public void setCancellationChargeAppliesAfterTime(Integer cancellationChargeAppliesAfterTime) {
this.cancellationChargeAppliesAfterTime = cancellationChargeAppliesAfterTime;
}

public String getTimeUnit() {
return timeUnit;
}

public void setTimeUnit(String timeUnit) {
this.timeUnit = timeUnit;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Category.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Category {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("display_name")
@Expose
private String displayName;
@SerializedName("currency")
@Expose
private String currency;
@SerializedName("distance_unit")
@Expose
private String distanceUnit;
@SerializedName("time_unit")
@Expose
private String timeUnit;
@SerializedName("eta")
@Expose
private Integer eta;
@SerializedName("distance")
@Expose
private String distance;
@SerializedName("ride_later_enabled")
@Expose
private String rideLaterEnabled;
@SerializedName("image")
@Expose
private String image;
@SerializedName("cancellation_policy")
@Expose
private CancellationPolicy cancellationPolicy;
@SerializedName("fare_breakup")
@Expose
private List<FareBreakup> fareBreakup = null;

public String getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getDisplayName() {
return displayName;
}

public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
this.displayName = displayName;
}

public String getCurrency() {
return currency;
}

public void setCurrency(String currency) {
this.currency = currency;
}

public String getDistanceUnit() {
return distanceUnit;
}

public void setDistanceUnit(String distanceUnit) {
this.distanceUnit = distanceUnit;
}

public String getTimeUnit() {
return timeUnit;
}

public void setTimeUnit(String timeUnit) {
this.timeUnit = timeUnit;
}

public Integer getEta() {
return eta;
}

public void setEta(Integer eta) {
this.eta = eta;
}

public String getDistance() {
return distance;
}

public void setDistance(String distance) {
this.distance = distance;
}

public String getRideLaterEnabled() {
return rideLaterEnabled;
}

public void setRideLaterEnabled(String rideLaterEnabled) {
this.rideLaterEnabled = rideLaterEnabled;
}

public String getImage() {
return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
this.image = image;
}

public CancellationPolicy getCancellationPolicy() {
return cancellationPolicy;
}

public void setCancellationPolicy(CancellationPolicy cancellationPolicy) {
this.cancellationPolicy = cancellationPolicy;
}

public List<FareBreakup> getFareBreakup() {
return fareBreakup;
}

public void setFareBreakup(List<FareBreakup> fareBreakup) {
this.fareBreakup = fareBreakup;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Discounts.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Discounts {

@SerializedName("discount_type")
@Expose
private Object discountType;
@SerializedName("discount_code")
@Expose
private Object discountCode;
@SerializedName("discount_mode")
@Expose
private Object discountMode;
@SerializedName("discount")
@Expose
private Integer discount;
@SerializedName("cashback")
@Expose
private Integer cashback;

public Object getDiscountType() {
return discountType;
}

public void setDiscountType(Object discountType) {
this.discountType = discountType;
}

public Object getDiscountCode() {
return discountCode;
}

public void setDiscountCode(Object discountCode) {
this.discountCode = discountCode;
}

public Object getDiscountMode() {
return discountMode;
}

public void setDiscountMode(Object discountMode) {
this.discountMode = discountMode;
}

public Integer getDiscount() {
return discount;
}

public void setDiscount(Integer discount) {
this.discount = discount;
}

public Integer getCashback() {
return cashback;
}

public void setCashback(Integer cashback) {
this.cashback = cashback;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Example.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

@SerializedName("result")
@Expose
private String result;
@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private Message message;

public String getResult() {
return result;
}

public void setResult(String result) {
this.result = result;
}

public Message getMessage() {
return message;
}

public void setMessage(Message message) {
this.message = message;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.FareBreakup.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class FareBreakup {

@SerializedName("type")
@Expose
private String type;
@SerializedName("minimum_distance")
@Expose
private Integer minimumDistance;
@SerializedName("minimum_time")
@Expose
private Integer minimumTime;
@SerializedName("base_fare")
@Expose
private Integer baseFare;
@SerializedName("minimum_fare")
@Expose
private Integer minimumFare;
@SerializedName("cost_per_distance")
@Expose
private Integer costPerDistance;
@SerializedName("waiting_cost_per_minute")
@Expose
private Integer waitingCostPerMinute;
@SerializedName("ride_cost_per_minute")
@Expose
private Double rideCostPerMinute;
@SerializedName("surcharge")
@Expose
private List<Object> surcharge = null;
@SerializedName("rates_lower_than_usual")
@Expose
private Boolean ratesLowerThanUsual;
@SerializedName("rates_higher_than_usual")
@Expose
private Boolean ratesHigherThanUsual;

public String getType() {
return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
this.type = type;
}

public Integer getMinimumDistance() {
return minimumDistance;
}

public void setMinimumDistance(Integer minimumDistance) {
this.minimumDistance = minimumDistance;
}

public Integer getMinimumTime() {
return minimumTime;
}

public void setMinimumTime(Integer minimumTime) {
this.minimumTime = minimumTime;
}

public Integer getBaseFare() {
return baseFare;
}

public void setBaseFare(Integer baseFare) {
this.baseFare = baseFare;
}

public Integer getMinimumFare() {
return minimumFare;
}

public void setMinimumFare(Integer minimumFare) {
this.minimumFare = minimumFare;
}

public Integer getCostPerDistance() {
return costPerDistance;
}

public void setCostPerDistance(Integer costPerDistance) {
this.costPerDistance = costPerDistance;
}

public Integer getWaitingCostPerMinute() {
return waitingCostPerMinute;
}

public void setWaitingCostPerMinute(Integer waitingCostPerMinute) {
this.waitingCostPerMinute = waitingCostPerMinute;
}

public Double getRideCostPerMinute() {
return rideCostPerMinute;
}

public void setRideCostPerMinute(Double rideCostPerMinute) {
this.rideCostPerMinute = rideCostPerMinute;
}

public List<Object> getSurcharge() {
return surcharge;
}

public void setSurcharge(List<Object> surcharge) {
this.surcharge = surcharge;
}

public Boolean getRatesLowerThanUsual() {
return ratesLowerThanUsual;
}

public void setRatesLowerThanUsual(Boolean ratesLowerThanUsual) {
this.ratesLowerThanUsual = ratesLowerThanUsual;
}

public Boolean getRatesHigherThanUsual() {
return ratesHigherThanUsual;
}

public void setRatesHigherThanUsual(Boolean ratesHigherThanUsual) {
this.ratesHigherThanUsual = ratesHigherThanUsual;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Message.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Message {

@SerializedName("categories")
@Expose
private List<Category> categories = null;
@SerializedName("ride_estimate")
@Expose
private List<RideEstimate> rideEstimate = null;

public List<Category> getCategories() {
return categories;
}

public void setCategories(List<Category> categories) {
this.categories = categories;
}

public List<RideEstimate> getRideEstimate() {
return rideEstimate;
}

public void setRideEstimate(List<RideEstimate> rideEstimate) {
this.rideEstimate = rideEstimate;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.RideEstimate.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class RideEstimate {

@SerializedName("category")
@Expose
private String category;
@SerializedName("distance")
@Expose
private Double distance;
@SerializedName("travel_time_in_minutes")
@Expose
private Integer travelTimeInMinutes;
@SerializedName("amount_min")
@Expose
private Integer amountMin;
@SerializedName("amount_max")
@Expose
private Integer amountMax;
@SerializedName("discounts")
@Expose
private Discounts discounts;

public String getCategory() {
return category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
this.category = category;
}

public Double getDistance() {
return distance;
}

public void setDistance(Double distance) {
this.distance = distance;
}

public Integer getTravelTimeInMinutes() {
return travelTimeInMinutes;
}

public void setTravelTimeInMinutes(Integer travelTimeInMinutes) {
this.travelTimeInMinutes = travelTimeInMinutes;
}

public Integer getAmountMin() {
return amountMin;
}

public void setAmountMin(Integer amountMin) {
this.amountMin = amountMin;
}

public Integer getAmountMax() {
return amountMax;
}

public void setAmountMax(Integer amountMax) {
this.amountMax = amountMax;
}

public Discounts getDiscounts() {
return discounts;
}

public void setDiscounts(Discounts discounts) {
this.discounts = discounts;
}

}
```

Now compile a library  compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2' 
then write few line to get your data fill in class

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
Example example = gson.fromJson(mainObj, Example.class);
```

Now you can try to fetch your categories like  this

```
example.getCategories();
```